# Why do Flutter Builds in Android Studio fail from button, but not from terminal?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, fish

Simply tells me when I press that green triangle that cocoapods isn't installed, but when I do Flutter Run in the AS terminal, it works. Notably I changed my default shell to fish and did so in the flutter settings, I rebooted and logged out before too. It also works in Visual Studio Code